# InnoDB duplicate insert on transaction commit

Tags: php, mysql, sql, innodb

I've been trying to get transactions working on my local WAMP server running MySQL and DB structure InnoDB, but whenever I `commit` the transaction, all queries are executed twice.

I have created a fairly simply script to insert **two** users:

```
$db = new \PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$db->beginTransaction();

try {
    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, created_at) VALUES ('user1', 'user1@mail.com', 0)");
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, created_at) VALUES ('user2', 'user2@mail.com', 1)");
    $stmt->execute();

    $db->commit();
    echo 'Success';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    echo "An error occurred {$e->getMessage()}";
}
```

Expected is that if there are no errors, two users are created. In stead **four** users are inserted.

[image]

I have tried `SET autocommit=0;` before starting the transaction but that made no difference.

UPDATED

User Will suggested looking at the access logs and there was the solution. Google Chrome **ALWAYS** attempts to get the favicon.ico (even when it isn't specified) due to apache2 redirecting all requests (except for files that exist) to the `index.php`, the current request is also **ALWAYS** executed again.

Comment: Sorry for these questions but we need to be sure : was the db empty before your test ? Did your script only ran once ?

Comment: Yes, before I run the script I remove all (but the first) users to get a clean test result.

Comment: show how this is called (some JS somewhere on a web page, at the cli , in a shell script  ????)

Comment: Also, can you change your query to insert time() in the created_at column ? It may help

Comment: @YvesLeBorg it's just an index.php called via GET. Also Will I can change any value to anything, but that doesn't stop the queries from being executed twice.

Comment: Try removing first  $stmt->execute(); ; you have two stmt and you call them twice. Or change one stmt into stmt2 and one $stmt->execute(); into $stmt2->execute();

Comment: @ikiK I just tested that to be sure and without the `$stmt->execute()` the `$db->commit()` doesn't add anything to the database.

Comment: Did you try other thing I suggested? Make one insert $stmt2 = $db->prepare AND $stmt2->execute();

Comment: @ikiK You are absolutely correct. Having a single execute didn't occur to me at all. Would you like to place your comment as the Question?

Comment: Is it working now?

Comment: @ikiK apoligies - apparently the last statement is now executed twice, resulting in the last statement within the `prepare` to be executed twice.

Comment: Insert a real timestamp in created_at can help figuring out if the statements are executed at the same time

Comment: Also, can you maybe show us your full script ? The problem may be in the rest of your code

Comment: @Will this is literally the full script. There is no framework, there are no additional querybuilders, models or framework. This is all there is to it, that's why it baffles my mind.

Comment: ow..
Maybe have a look to your access_log (if using apache) and be sure the script is only called once ?

Comment: @Will I think you're onto something. I just looked at the chrome network logs and chrome attempts to "get" the favicon.ico which doesn't exist, apache redirects the request to index.php and it looks like the request is executed there as well.

Comment: Great, finally something ! :)

Answer (score -1):

Put your $db->beginTransaction(); inside try statement.

```
$db = new \PDO($dsn, $username, $password);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



try {
$db->beginTransaction();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, created_at) VALUES ('user1', 'user1@mail.com', 0)");
    $stmt->execute();

    $stmt = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username, email, created_at) VALUES ('user2', 'user2@mail.com', 1)");
    $stmt->execute();

    $db->commit();
    echo 'Success';
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $db->rollBack();
    echo "An error occurred {$e->getMessage()}";
}
```

Comment: User @Will has put me on the right track, apparently Chrome always gets the favicon.ico even when it isn't specfiied - apache2 redirects requests (except for files that exist) to the index.php meaning that the /favicon.ico route always redirects to the index.php if there is ***no*** favicon.